# Parsing JSON in Objective C with key names as incremented integers

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

not really sure how to even word this question BUT I have some JSON that I need to parse which is formatted like so:-

```
"nodes": {
    "4": {
        "node_id": 4,
        "title": "TITLE 1",
        "description": "",
    },
    "7": {
        "node_id": 7,
        "title": "TITLE 2",
        "description": "",
    },
    "12": {
        "node_id": 12,
        "title": "TITLE 3",
        "description": "",
    },
```

Normally I would grab values with the standard [dictionary objectForKey@"key"] but as the items begin with an integer (string) I am finding it hard to parse correctly. Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: Using [dictionary objectForKey:@"4"]; will still work, they are strings, not integers

Comment: try using [dictionary allKeys] to return all keys inside an array

Comment: @jammycoder, that doesn't work for me since these vales can change at any time. I need to be able to call a key!

Comment: *Why* are you finding it hard to parse? Because you don't know what keys to use? Will Roberts' comment addresses that. Otherwise, please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to access one value than you would do the following.

```
// Assume JSONObject is the "root" dictionary
NSDictionary *fourDictionary = JSONObject[@"nodes"]["4"] // This will get the object from "4":{}
```

Now if the JSON in question can have a dynamic number of objects than this is much trickier. The easiest solution would be to get the provider of the JSON to rewrite it as an array of objects. You could than look up the object you want using the object's node_id value.

If this is not possible than you could attempt to write a for loop to loop through all of the keys in the "nodes" object and access the items from the dictionary that way.

i.e.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfNodes = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *nodes = JSONObject[@"nodes"];
for(NSString *numberKey in [nodes allKeys])
{
    NSDictionary *nodeObject = nodes[numberKey]
    [arrayOfNodes addObject:nodeObject];
}
// Do anything else with the nodes now that they are in an array.
```

Comment: Yeah, the loop has done the trick so will go with that idea. Thank you :)

Comment: Perfect! Had the same issue, but with random numbers rather than incremental numbers. Also you don't have to store the nodes in an array, you could just loop the dictionary key/value pairs using the ```allKeys``` array. (And then store the data in your own custom objects or whatever you need to do with it).